# How to allow all Operations and Namespaces

Tags: wcf

I'm new to WCF, but not new to C# and .Net. and am using Visual Studio 2008 and .Net 3.5.

I'm trying to build a Web Service that can receive any inbound Request XML and any namespaces. It would behave like a transparent receiver and simply intake the inbound request XML.

Once I get the request I'm going to pass it to some custom .Net C# Project to invoke a MQPUT to IBM MQ Series.

Right now I have the WCF Web Service Application receiving a generic inbound operation called RunTest(). I consume the WSDL into SoapUI, build a sample request and breakpoint and it works. But, when I try to pass our company request XML it doesn't land on the breakpoint.

Here is the ServiceContract and Operation:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="IService1",Namespace="cfg-env=http://www.co.com/schemas/cfg-     env/")]
//[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{


[OperationContract]
void RunTest();

[OperationContract]
void CFX();
```

Here is the Method for the Operation:

```
public void RunTest()
{  <<<it does break here using the request from the WSDL
string serviceName;
string queueManager;
string queue;
string requestMessage;

//Capture the Service Name
serviceName = "";

//Save the QueueManager
queueManager = "";

//Save the Request Queue
queue = "";

//Save the Message
requestMessage = "";

//Call MQ Put
Engine eng = new Engine();
try
{
eng.Put(serviceName, queue, requestMessage, queueManager);            
}
```

The main thing I need to do is receive the inbound XML, interogate it for a few pieces of information and call this Method to do the MQPUT function on MQ.

The inbound namespace will look like the above but I'd like to ensure I can receive and interogate any XPATH that may be namespace qualified. If I have to I can work with the cfg-env namespace prefix exclusively as our services do use that as a standard.

What are my key hurdles in doing this in VS 2008 WCF? If you have any links please pass them along if you can.

Comment: Why do you _want_ to do this with WCFm if it's HTTP and XML that's going around? A simple IIS module or so will suffice, allowing easier access to the HTTP layer and the raw messages. :)

Comment: So, when you try to pass your company request XML it doesn't land on the breakpoint?? there are no parameters in RunTest that takes your companies xml input.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you specify the name property on the OperationContract attribute as "*" to accept all requests. To make the parameter itself schema agnostic, it should be of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.

Comment: can you give me a snipet of how to set the type on the Name attribute? Do I cast?

Comment: Sorry, it's not the Name property of the OperationContract attribute. It's the Action. So [OperationContract(Action = "*")]. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What you are building is a "WCF router".

Included in the latest .NET release is a configurable [Routing Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517421.aspx).

If the routing service doesn't meet your needs, building your own router is possible but can get really complicated when secure messages are a requirement. This set of MSDN articles is the best resource. They answer your question of how to have a service accept any message, and then continue on into addressing and security issues.

[Building a WCF Router, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx)

[Building a WCF Router, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546553.aspx)